# Group two divs on one another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Maybe its kind of dumb but it still doesn't work. I,m trying to wrap two divs of different class with another div but my current input just closes divs automatically.

There are several sets of divs with .panel-heading and .panel-body classes that are on sets of two.

Im trying to wrap each pair around with a div with .panel panel-default class, but my code closes divs so it just creates two empty divs. I don't know whats wrong with my code. Im using jquery

```
    <html>
<body>
<div class="panel-head"></div>
<div class="panel-body"></div>
<div class="panel-head"></div>
<div class="panel-body"></div>
<div class="panel-head"></div>
<div class="panel-body"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the jquery

```
$('div.panel-head').before (
'<div class="panel panel-default">');
$('div.panel-body').after ('</div>');
```

But this code creates two divs automatically closing and opening tags not allowing to wrapping around. I can't create jsfiddle becuase im on a smartphone and can't use internet on pc please someone enlighten me on how to bypass this behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took this from [here](https://gist.github.com/BigglesZX/747490):

```
$(".panel-head").each(function() {
    $(this).next(".panel-body").addBack().wrapAll("<div class='panel panel-default' />")
});
```

**EDIT**

Originally it used `andSelf()` but it is deprecated, I change it with `addBack()`

Comment: Note that `andSelf` is deprecated in favour of [`addBack`](https://api.jquery.com/addBack/)

Comment: So this code will get divs of class .panel-head that have a .panel-body div after right? I only have a doubt why is index set on function value?

Comment: Indeed. The `index` is not necessary as it is not used. I will delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is what you're looking for. You will have to do some error checking (e.g. length of heads and bodies must be the same).

```js
// Get all heads and bodies
var $phead = $('.panel-head');
var $pbody = $('.panel-body');

// loop to create default panel and insert head and body
for (int i = 0; i < $phead.length; i++)
  {
    var h = $($phead[i]);
    var b = $($pbody[i]);
    
    // create new div
    var d = $('<div />', class: 'panel-default');
    // append body and head
    h.appendTo(d);
    b.appendTo(d);
    
    //append new div to body
    $('body').append(d);
}
```

Comment: this solution worked fine but the other one adjusted better, but this one is better for handling bigger object chains, thanks